# What is this font in the picture?

Tags: typography

[image]

I would like to know what font it is.f

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean with "typography"? The font face or the way to achieve that output or ...?

Comment: Welcome, can you ask google to translate your question from your mother tongue to english and edit the question? Right now, i am not sure what your question is.

Comment: The font face i mean

Comment: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)

Comment: Do you have the pdf of the above text? If yes, you can look at the properties which font was used.

Comment: Okey the fonts used are: CMBX CMSC CMBXT CMEX CMMI CMR CMSY LASY  MSMBM EUFM with different numbers all of them

Comment: @matemagreek It's the default setting with LaTeX.